# Un chiste que no se traduce bien

Tags: traducción, conjugación, ambigüedad, morfología

Hay un chiste que quiero expresar en español. "A liar, a thief and a politician enter a bar. Then, a second man arrives." Al escuchar la primera sentencia, no se sabe que el sujeto es plural porque el verbo "enter" puede indicar un sujeto singular también. Sólo queda claro al oír las palabras "second" y "him" al final. No obstante, en español ya no hay ambigüedad:

"Un mentiroso, un ladrón y un político entra en un bar. Luego llega un segundo hombre." Hay una distinción obvia entre "entra" y "entran" y el chiste ya no suena tan bueno. ¿Hay mejor traducción? No quiero revelar al principio del chiste que el mentiroso, el ladrón y el político son la misma persona.

Comment: Un camerero vio entrar en su bar un mentiroso, un ladrón y un político.  Entonces, entró una segunda persona

Comment: I think "A" should be used, but then the joke could be spoilt: *.. vio entrar A un mentiroso, un ladrón y un político vs. vio entrar A un mentiroso, A un ladrón y A un político...*

Comment: @Gustavson La falta de la preposición lo hace más genérico, cosa que va bien para mí.  Lo bueno es que el verbo *ver* como unos cuantos verbos, deja la opción, con *ver* y *hombre*, parece que el uso queda en algo que rodea 1:5::sin:con. La falta de ella lo hace más genérico (o por lo menos, para mí)

Comment: ¿Se podría formular con una expresión impersonal que utilizara "haber", ya que tales frases son de las pocas que no se declinen? "En el bar había un mentiroso, un ladrón, y un político. Entonces, entró una segunda persona".

Answer (score 1):

### A liar, a thief and a politician enter a bar. Then, a second man arrives

> un mentiroso, un ladrón y un político entrando a un bar. Al rato, una segunda persona

Comment: ¡Qué bueno verte de nuevo por el sitio respondiendo preguntas!

Comment: Disculpe, quería usar el pretérito; "a liar, a thief and a politician entered a bar..."

Comment: Ah, bien. En ese caso quizás funcionaría decir: `se vio entrando a un bar a un mentiroso, a un político ya un ladrón; detrás suyo, alguien más,`

Comment: o: `vieron entrar a un bar a un mentiroso, un polítco y un ladrón, seguido de él,  un segundo sujeto`

Answer (score 1):

La premisa es incorrecta. En tercera persona, la forma "enter" en inglés solo se puede utilizar para un sujeto plural. En singular sería:

- A liar (...) **enters** a bar.

Por esta razón, pienso que el uso del plural *entran*:

- Un mentiroso, un ladrón y un político entran en un bar. Después, llega un segundo hombre.

es la traducción más fiel al original.

Comment: Disculpe, quería usar el pretérito; "a liar, a thief and a politician enterED a bar..."